# Weird scope in 3rd level class when used output buffering

Tags: php, scope

I have a master class and semi-master class. Master class core is a class that prints all head, nav, footer and meta elements. Class Base prints content related data and all page-level classes extend it and print their data within specific div.

My problem is that functions and globals are not within scope in one of functions within Base class. Where did I go wrong?

```
abstract class Core {
     abstract protected function print_content();
}

abstract class Base extends Core {
    abstract protected function print_page_content();
    public function print_content(){
      ob_start();
      $this->get_nav();
      $output = ob_get_contents();
      $output .= ' ... '.$this->print_page_content().' ...';
      ob_end_clean();
  }
}

class Page extends Base {
  private function get_games(){...}
  private function process_form(){...}

  public function print_page_content(){
    $this->process_form();  # <--- function doesn't see it (!)
    $output = '..... '.$this->get_games().' .... '; # <-- function DOES see this tho (!)
    $GLOBALS['m_id']; # <-- or any other global such as $_GET, $_POST is not under scope.
    return $output;
 }
```

When I do error reporting it doesn't print any error. It just ignores line where function was called.

However, When I would force error, error would appear.

Comment: What attempts have you made? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of your function, run it and it should output an error.

Comment: It doesn't print any error. It just ignores line where function was called. When I would force error, error would appear.

Comment: When forced, what is that error? your own defined error I am assuming?

Comment: a) ob_start(); followed immediately by ob_get_contents() - what's the point? b) $output .= ... $this->print_page_content() expects print_page_content() to return something; your code snpipet doesn't indiciate it does.

Comment: Actually there is some code between. I edited question for that purpose. And yes print_page_content() has return $output at the end.

Comment: Can you make it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @VolkerK https://3v4l.org/CpelP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on the technical aspect (and not smaller glitches or design decisions).
I don't think the code snippet you've posted "contains" the error. Let me give you a version that contains everything you've shown us and only adds things that do not "collide" with your code snippet, i.e. minimal implementations of what you've left out (again: purely technical).

```
<?php
abstract class Core {
    abstract protected function print_content();
}

abstract class Base extends Core {
    abstract protected function print_page_content();
    public function print_content(){
        ob_start();
        $this->get_nav();
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        $output .= '###'.$this->print_page_content().'###';
        ob_end_clean();

        echo $output;
    }

    public function get_nav() {
        echo '| Base::get_nav |';
    }
}

class Page extends Base {
    protected $names = array();
    private function get_games(){ return htmlspecialchars(var_export($this->names, true)); }
    private function process_form(){ $this->names['Jean']="D'Arc"; $this->names['John']='Malkovich';}

    public function print_page_content(){
        $this->process_form();
        $output = '<pre>'.$this->get_games().'</pre>';
        $output .= '<p>'.$GLOBALS['m_id'].'</p>';
        return $output;
    }
}

$m_id = 4711;
$p = new Page;
$p->print_content();
```

it prints

```
| Base::get_nav |###<pre>array (
  'Jean' =&gt; 'D\'Arc',
  'John' =&gt; 'Malkovich',
)</pre><p>4711</p>###
```

( check here: https://3v4l.org/ZBQ0b )

as it is supposed to do.
So, where does *your* script differ from *this* script? Try to minimize your script for testing purposes in order to find the cause.

---

edit: suggested improvement(s) for your sscce

```
  private function process_form(){
    // $stmt = add your prepare()/statement here as a comment
    $params = array(/* put in all the variables here, you would bind*/);
    // <-- maybe the actual bind code here as comment -->
    return var_export( $params, true );

  }#endfunc(process_form)

  public function print_page_content(){
    $pf = $this->process_form();
    $output = 'print_page_content stuff...'.$this->get_games()
        .' <pre>'.$pf.'</pre>';
    return $output;
  }#endfunc(print_page_content)
```

Comment: It took me some time to cut all stuff from my scripts. Here it goes: https://3v4l.org/CpelP

Comment: Excellent, A for effort ;-) One more thing: It's 4am around here and I should have been in bed for ...ages. Right now the output of your sscce doesn't look wrong to me. Is it? And if so: where,what? ;-)

Comment: At start of public function print_page_content  $this->process_form() is called which should return 'test' string. However if you call that function within $output variable, it does print 'test' string. there is no 'test' in output. 4 am here too :)

Comment: Oh, right. Your process_form() function _returns_ something. I assumed (in my example) it was just processing and storing the state. Ok, in your code you're doing nothing with the return value; you call the method and then the return value is lost. Where you want it to go/have an effect?

Comment: Actually in real code, process_form() returns nothing. It checks form input and then uses SQL prepared statement to insert data into SQL table. This is just example with returning output strings to represent scope problem.

Comment: Hm, then your sscce doesn't illustrate the problem? From "SQL prepared" and "scope problem" I assume you could change the sscce to at least show what "kind" of variables you want to use, and how. see edit:. And in case you rely on global variables there (though you shouldn't....) please define them with mock values in the sscce.

Comment: Its kinda weird. It  has something to do with output buffering. When I put that function (the one that inserts SQL data into tables) into string within $output, it works very well.

Comment: hm, hard to tell then. I can't imagine right now what the (darned) output buffer can do to a prepared statement and the variable scope. So, my instinct tells me: that's not it. Maybe _now_ (or now+8hrs of sleep) is a good time for you to get familiar with a [debugger](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html) ;-)

Comment: I am really grateful for your time. I will make a deeper research into this problem and then provide more legit question.

Comment: and another tip: You've now tried to condense the fully fledged script into an sscce (from big to small). In the case you've described it might be more fruitful to do the opposite: start with a very small/basic script that _does_ that part and then put in all the other stuff step by step until it breaks (from small to big). I.e. start with a class (not inheriting/implementing anything) with just `public function process_form()` and provide it with anything it needs in the most minimal way possible, test it, and then work it up from there.

Comment: A very fine tip. I am grateful. I'll use that approach when I am going to write next SSCCE

Comment: Along the way you might be able to get rid of the output buffer all together ;-)

Comment: Hardly possible because I do not print content from top to bottom. Content printed from all classes expect from master class is printed somewhere in the middle inside containers.

Comment: Other templating/content managing systems have managed, and so can you ;-)

Answer (score -2):

After the abstract class is inherited, the abstract method cannot be rewritten.

Comment: previously declared abstract in father class, then you can't inherit father abstract function.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example? I don't get what you mean.